# Disable GUI while running Wine setup

Tags: bash, user-interface, installation, wine

I want to be able to run

```
env `WINEPREFIX="/home/$(whoami)/.callix-wine" WINEARCH="win32" wine "wineboot"`
```

without having the little window pop up (turn the GUI off):

[image: wine-popup]

Is there some sort of argument that I can pass or some sort of variable to use in order to do this? Also, will this argument or variable work with all bash commands?

I want this window to be off in order to install wine with no fuss in a makefile. Also, I did look up everything I could think of to do this, but I don't know where to start or if it is even possible. Thank you.

Comment: @Downvoter Can you explain why you downvoted? I'd be happy to improve the question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a file called `wine-setup.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Make a new WINEPREFIX in the user's home directory entitled ".wine"
env `WINEPREFIX="/home/$(whoami)/.wine" WINEARCH="win32" wine "wineboot"`
```

Run the file with `xvfb-run ./wine-setup.sh`... and no window appears!

Comment: Awesome, this was very useful to get wine installed and setup within a docker container!